# How to float table in itext pdf

Tags: java, itext

I want the float the table to right but its not working.

```
public static String CreatePdf(String datapart1,String mobileNumber, String datapart2, String datapart3, String datapart4, String datapart5, String bankinfo, String time, String adminName) {
        QueryHelper qh = new QueryHelper();

          String copy = "<html>" + "<head>" + " <title></title>" + "<style>#demo{float:right;}</style>"
          + "</head>" + "<body>" +
          "<div class=\"row col-lg-12\">"+"<b><h1 style=\"text-align:center;\">\r\n" +
          "<u>Invoice</u>\r\n" + "</h1></b>\r\n" + "</div>" +
          "<div class=\"col-lg-12\"  style=\"width: 100%; height: 160px; margin-top: -6px \"><div class=\"col-md-6\" style=\"font-size: 13px; float: left; width: 50%; height: 160px;\">"
          + datapart1 + "</div>" +
          "<div style=\"width: 75%; height: 160px; font-size: 13px; float: right; text-align: left;\">"
          + bankinfo + "</div></div>" +
          "<div style=\"margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; width:100%;\"><table style=\"border:1px solid #ccc; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 12px;\">"
          + datapart2 + "</table>" +
          "<table style=\" border:1px solid #ccc; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 0px; float: right; border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 12px;\">"
          + datapart3 + "</table></div>" +
          "<div class=\"col-lg-12 row\" style=\"width:100%;\" ><div class=\"col-md-6\" style=\" float:left; width=:60%; \" > </div>"
          + "<div class=\"col-md-6\" style=\"height: auto;\"><table style=\" border:1px solid #ccc;width: 40%; margin-bottom: 20px; float:right; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: right; font-size: 12px;\" > "
          + datapart4 + "</table></div></div>" +
          "<table style=\" border:1px solid #ccc; width: 100%; font-size: 13px; text-align: center; border-collapse: collapse;\">"
          + datapart5 + "</table>"+""
                + "<table style=\"border:1px; float:center; \"> <tr> <td>demo</td></tr> </table>"
          + "</body>" + "</html>";

        /*
         * String copy="<html>"+ "<head>"+ "</head>"+ "<body>"+
         * bankinfo+"</body></html>";
         */
        String status = "fasle";
        System.out.println(copy);
        try {
            String filePath;
            Document document = new Document();
            Random rand = new Random();
            int rand_int1 = rand.nextInt(1000);
            String fileName = mobileNumber + rand_int1 + ".pdf";
            filePath = "/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.45/Invoice PDF/" + fileName;
            OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filePath));
            StringBuilder htmlString = new StringBuilder();
            htmlString.append(new String(copy));
//          System.out.println(htmlString);

            Image image;
            image = Image.getInstance("/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.45/webapps/images/zakas-20-20.png");

            document.open();
            document.add(image);
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlString.toString().getBytes());
            XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
            System.out.println("Method Pdf >> invoiceText " + writer);

//          document.add(new Chunk("\n"));
//          document.add(new Chunk("\t"));

            System.out.println(document);
            status = "true";



                document.close();
                writer.close();
                file.close();
            System.out.println("genrated");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }
```

Comment: please explain your question like what are you trying to do? what have you done so far? what kind of help will you expecting from us? and finally add some essential codes add also mention what kind of output did you get

Comment: i want the float the table to right but its not working .  @Kalana

Comment: Add your sample output

Comment: https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/faq/technical-support/itext-7/how-add-table-top-right-corner-page

Comment: I try to add an image output but not added @Kalana

Comment: Add link of image in comment section